# Chart of values from e.g. all mondays in a list of dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm managing an excel sheet with revenue from several bars. Each bar can have up to 3 shifts per day.

The sheet looks like this:

```
|date|bartender|bar|shift|revenue|
```

Each day can have several rows of entries in the sheet.

1)
I would like to be able to make a graph of the revenue of e.g. all mondays so far, with each monday so far getting it's own data point in the graph. Each monday also have to combine the revenue from all shifts that monday. I would also like the graph to automatically update itself when new rows are inserted to the sheet.

Is this possible?

2)
Also, is it  possible to create a sheet with a row with a list og unique dates in the original sheet and make that row so i don't have to manually expand the formula to the next row to update the list of unique dates when the original sheet gets new entries?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: All of what you ask is possible. For points 1, add a `Day` column, then a pivot table and filter only on Monday. Build your chart off that ... you may want to use  [Dynamic Named Ranges] http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm to help you chart. For point 2, you will most likely need VBA to get the newly entered dates added to your unique list.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you want by adding a "Day of the Week" column and using a pivot graph:

[image: PivotGraphExample1]
[image: PivotGraphExample2]

Good Luck.

**EDIT/ADDITION**

If you wanted to see all the Mondays split out seperately, you can do it like this:
[image: PivotChartExample]

Pivot charts are pretty flexible. You should be able to achieve whatever look you are going for. You can add more report filters for things like shifts too if you want. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I'm not sure this will solve my problem (please correct me if I'm mistaken) as I'm looking for a dynamically updatet chart where each monday has it's own bar. Not one with all mondays combined into one. Please correct me if I have misunderstood your suggestions.

Comment: That is simply a matter of re-arranging your axes. Use the unique value "Date" column as your horizontel axis if you want to see all the Mondays split out. Good Luck.